# Remove certain elements form string

Tags: r, rstudio

So I have vector which consist of

```
data<-c("Mark And (BD Marketing Da 1 Z _ 9793)",
"Andre All (BD Marketing DA 1 Z _ 9794 (plus))", 
"Alli Inn (BD Sport Educ 1 C _ 9722 (plus))",
"Alli Inn (BP Sport Educ 1 Z _ 9347)")
```

And now I need to remove all characters up to **_** and also both **parenthesis** where it is missing the word (plus) so the outcome should be

```
Mark And BD Marketing Da 1 Z
Andre All BD Marketing DA 1 Z (plus)
Alli Inn BD Sport Educ 1 C (plus)
Alli Inn BP Sport Educ 1 Z
```

I used
`gsub("\\s*\\w*$", "", data)` and got

```
Alli Inn (BP Sport Educ 1 Z
```

but this is not correct as I need to remove other parenthesis and also keep (plus) where it is written.

I have tried this:
`gsub('\((?!plus)|(?<!plus)\)|.\\d+', '', rownames(data), perl=TRUE)` and got this 
`Alli Inn BP Sport Educ Z` but now I am missing **number 1 before letter**

Comment: For future reference, what you have is a vector, not a data frame. A data frame _contains_ one or more vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gsub('\\((?!plus)|(?<!plus)\\)|_ [0-9]*', '', data, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "Mark And BD Marketing Da 1 Z "        
#[2] "Andre All BD Marketing DA 1 Z  (plus)"
#[3] "Alli Inn BD Sport Educ 1 C  (plus)"   
#[4] "Alli Inn BP Sport Educ 1 Z "
```

Comment: If a do this i still have numbers like this: Mark And BD Marketing Da 1 Z 9793, i think that i sohuld change something in _ [0-9] in order to also remove numbers?

Comment: I have tried this:'gsub('\\((?!plus)|(?<!plus)\\)|.\\d+', '', rownames(data), perl=TRUE)' and got this 'Alli Inn BP Sport Educ  Z' but now i am missing number 1 before letter

Comment: Can you post the code that you ran and the result that you get? Because I used your data and have shown it to work.

Comment: I think this is the case. The thing is the code is too big to show, I combined this data vector from data frame with rownames(data)<-paste0(sapply(data.average[rownames(data),"NAME"]), " (", data.average[rownames(data),"ID"], ")") and structure of this two combined columns is "character". So my data in the original post are structured from code rownames(data)....

Comment: I past the result in original post at the end.

Comment: What do you want me to say? You gave me this `"Alli Inn (BP Sport Educ 1 Z _ 9347)"` and I gave you this `"Alli Inn BP Sport Educ 1 Z "`. Now you say when you run it, it doesn't work. I'm showing you that it works. If you have another example that doesn't work, then post that example to the question and we'll try it.

Comment: Yes it works. Before I had a bug in my code and  therefore was not working properly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

using dplyr and stringr this might be quick and dirty, but it does the job:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
data %>% 
  str_replace_all(" _ [1-9][0-9]{0,3}|\\(|\\)", "") %>% 
  str_replace_all("plus", "(plus)")
```